# create a custom wordpress page template of your design

Tags: wordpress

How to write a page content over the featured image with specific design in a wordpress?I have tried a lot but it doesnot work. So any suggestions? Please help

Comment: Here is a possible duplicate [Creating a custom page template in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563691/creating-a-custom-page-template-in-wordpress)

Comment: Read here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a custom page template in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563691/creating-a-custom-page-template-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<?php 
/* 
* Template Name: yourtie 
*/
get_header(); 
?> 
<section id="cir-content-area" role="main">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12"> 
       <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       <?php $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full');  ?>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="background:url('<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>') no-repeat scroll center center / cover">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php the_content();   ?>
        </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?> 
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/